# Top Border in Android Text View

Tags: android, textview

How can set top border to Android Text view using xml ? Please can some one give a sample code

Comment: What do you mean by setting top border of TextView.Can you share a screen shot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes create 9-patch image with top border and set into `TextView` by using `android:background`